# Reading CSV files with non-standard delimiters into Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file (one of many files I need to read for my project, but only one with the problem below) created by a third-party software that uses /t (sic!) as a delimiter (and it is NOT a tab-delimited file, note the difference between /t and \t, and please do not link this to tab-delimited topics any more :).

For example, the file looks as follow:

```
"Field label 1"/t"Field label 2"/t"Field label 3"
"Data1"/t"Data2"/t"Data3"
```

I use a following function to read my CSV files into dataframes:

```
def read_and_filter(file_path, cols_to_keep, delimiter_char=GLOBAL_CSV_DELIMITER, 
                                                quote_char=GLOBAL_CSV_QUOTECHAR,
                                                use_encoding=GLOBAL_ENCODING):
    """
    file_path (str): path to file with data
    cols_to_keep (list): columns to keep in the dataframe
    """
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=delimiter_char, quotechar=quote_char, encoding=use_encoding, dtype=str)
    print(df.columns.tolist())
    df = df[cols_to_keep]
    # replace newlines in the data fields to accommodate for RFC-4180 non-compliant consumers of the dataset.
    df = replace_newlines(df=df, replacement_str=" ")

    return df
```

The default parameters are set as:

```
GLOBAL_ENCODING = "utf-8"
GLOBAL_CSV_DELIMITER = ","
GLOBAL_CSV_QUOTECHAR = '"'
COLUMNS_TO_KEEP = ["Field label 1", "Field label 3"]
```

function invoked as (now this is correct):

```
    my_df = read_and_filter(file_path=my_csv_file, cols_to_keep=COLUMNS_TO_KEEP, delimiter_char="/t")
```

The function crashes at the unnecessary column removal because it cannot find Field label 3. It turns out that Pandas removes quotes only from the first column label but keeps them around the rest.

```
['Field label 1', '"Field label 2"', '"Field label 3"']
```

Question, how to force Pandas to read the dataframe correctly (as in by removing quotes around the fields)? Or, if it is not possible, any suggestions for workarounds?

Comment: Tab is a pretty standard delimiter.

Comment: If really a `/t` and not `\t` that doesn't change much: `pd.read_csv(filename, sep='/t', engine='python')`

Comment: This is not even a close to a tab-delimited file. The delimiter used is "/t", which is not even an escape sequence for tab ("\t"). Also, the fields in tab-delimited files are actually separated by an ASCII 9. I am reading one such file from another source successfully.

Comment: I realized I had included the wrong function call in my example (now fixed). Tried with engine='python', but to no avail.

Comment: Does it help if you specify `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` ?

Comment: It did not; right now I use a workaround involving pre-processing of the file and replacing the '"/t"' with '","'.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('"Field label 1"/t"Field label 2"/t"Field label 3"\n"Data1"/t"Data2"/t"Data3"'), sep='/t', engine='python')` works fine. Please give a reproducible example that doesn't work

Comment: Thanks to your example, due to this I also found out what was wrong with the file. The file had BOM byte order mark (three bytes in the beginning that you do not see when loading the file into text editors like Notepad++). Without BOM, everything works fine, with BOM (0xee 0xbb 0xbf in m case) you get the result I showed.